# How can I make a minimal deployment of a Next.js non-static app?

Tags: npm, next.js

The way Next.JS documentation and other tutorials describe how to deploy a non-static app (i.e. one that you run with `npm run start`) seems to leave a lot of unnecessary stuff in the app. They say to just run `npm run build`, and then run `npm run start` and congrats, you're done!

This is strange to me because when other systems such as Webpack create a deployable version, it is much more minimal. By **minimal** I mean it doesn't contain

- `devDependencies` in `node_modules`
- unminified source files (mine are TypeScript)
- other miscellaneous stuff like React Storybook stories, etc.

In my case, this extra stuff adds up to hundreds of megabytes.

I've got a partial solution that looks like this:

1. Run `npm run build`
2. Make a new folder and copy `node_modules`, `.next`, `static`, `package.json`, and a couple other things into it
3. `cd` to the new folder and run `npm prune --production` to remove dev dependencies

This basically works but I'm not entirely happy with it. For one thing, `node_modules` still contains a lot of stuff that isn't needed. In a Webpack product this stuff would be ignored due to tree shaking. For another, I have a couple other app-specific folders I have to remember to copy over.

Why is this so hard? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Asked a question similar to this in the Next discussion forum, so in case it helps anyone else with a similar question: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14339

Answer (score 6):

##### UPDATE

In `nextjs@13.x.x` standalone output becomes stable (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/output#automatically-copying-traced-files) now
`next.config.js` will be:

```
module.exports = {
  output: 'standalone',
};
```

---

#### Old Answer for version 12

Starting from `next@12.x.x` you can create a standalone build that drops all unnecessary dependencies (bundle size is reduced by 70%-80%).
To use it you can just set this in your `next.config.js` (as described here https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing#automatically-copying-traced-files-experimental)

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  }
}
```

- Run `next build`
- This will create a folder at `.next/standalone`
- Then instead of `next start` you must use the `server.js` file generated in the .next/standalone folder `node .next/standalone/server.js`

---

##### Docker Environment

if you are in a docker environment you should also copy the static folder

```
...
COPY ./next.config.js ./
COPY ./public ./public
COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs ./.next/standalone ./
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs /.next/static ./.next/static
....

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: This is now simply `modules.exports = { output: 'standalone' }`

Comment: This is probably my own inexperience with Next.JS but I found that running `node .next/standalone/server.js` didn't load assets but if I run `cd .next/standalone && node server.js` the assets load fine.

Comment: The Next.js documentation says this "copies only the necessary files for a production deployment including select files in `node_modules`". What does "select files" mean? Does this actually do any bundling/tree shaking so as to be equivalent to a Webpack production build?